# simplifying jQuery selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

In writing a plugin, I found myself needing a dynamic system to select specific elements or groups of elements to execute code on. While the code I have works totally fine, I feel like their might be a better way to do it but can't seem to scrounge anything up.

```
$('map[name='+ elem.clicklight.mapName +'] > area[data-group='+ event.target.area.group +']').each(function() {
    //some stuff to do
});
```

As you can see, that is absurdly long and annoying to read. For all I know this is the best way to do it, but if anyone had any comments on it I would appreciate it.

Comment: Is this a common selected, or are there common aspects like this that you could wrap into a "selector generator" function? For example, passing the `elem.clicklight.mapName` and `event.target.area.group` as parameters (or even `elem` and `event`) that could return the selector you have?

Comment: It is common, in my main plugin body I have that and the same thing duplicated for a click event. I did realize I could get one step better by replacing `event.target` with `this` instead. I did not think of a selector function though, that would certainly clean things up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a common code @Turk.

But you can mind in using variables to make your selector shorter..

Something simple like:

```
var el_name = elem.clicklight.mapName;
var evt_tgt = event.target.area.group;

$('map[name='+ el_name +'] > area[data-group='+ evt_tgt +']').each(function() {
    //some stuff to do
});
```

Comment: Yea that's what I ended up doing. JavaScript just always makes me feel like I am writing bad code as I try and learn it haha. Glad to hear I was doing it appropriately anyway.

Comment: haha it's a normal selector's expression, but i understand your feeling about coding in JavaScript. You're welcome @Turk!